# problem to display PrimeCharacterEntity "&Prime;"

Tags: php, mysql, html-entities

Hello I have this value in mysql database

```
 ACER Press Conference First Look: 4.8&Prime;, 7&Prime; & 10.1&Prime; Tablets
```

when display it on the web using php, it look like this

```
ACER Press Conference First Look: 4.8&Prime;, 7&Prime; & 10.1&Prime; Tablets
```

instead of this
ACER Press Conference First Look: 4.8″, 7″ & 10.1″ Tablets

I used these two functions to insert it to database

```
$title        = mb_convert_encoding($_POST['title'],'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');
$title=mysql_real_escape_string($title);
```

then display it as xml feed using joomla module "mod_syndicate" and send it to twitter connect
using com_autotweet

any help please?

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you’re using [`htmlentities`](http://php.net/htmlentities) to sanitize the output but don’t want to double encode already existing character references, set the fourth parameter *double_encode* of `htmlentities` to false:

```
$str = 'ACER Press Conference First Look: 4.8&Prime;, 7&Prime; & 10.1&Prime; Tablets';

echo htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1', true);
// => ACER Press Conference First Look: 4.8&amp;Prime;, 7&amp;Prime; & 10.1&amp;Prime; Tablets

echo htmlentities($str, ENT_COMPAT, 'ISO-8859-1', false);
// => ACER Press Conference First Look: 4.8&Prime;, 7&Prime; & 10.1&Prime; Tablets
```

Comment: @FDI: And how do you output that data? Please take a look at the plain HTML code output to see if `&Prime;` is not actually `&amp;Prime;`.

Comment: this is html code output
ACER Press Conference First Look: 4.8&Prime;, 7&Prime; & 10.1&Prime; Tablets 
output using joomla module "mod_syndicate"